# Visual Studio Errors: C2672 & C2780

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting several errors within my code and as I am new to C++ am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong and what the solution would be. I have googled around a fair bit but nothing I have found has made sense so if anyone can give me some help it would be amazing so that I can learn from this.

The errors are all on line 23 which is search(token);

```
Error   C2672   'search': no matching overloaded function found TakeTwo d:\desktop\twittersearch\taketwo\taketwo\taketwo.cpp    23  
Error   C2780   '_FwdIt1 std::search(_FwdIt1,_FwdIt1,_FwdIt2,_FwdIt2)': expects 4 arguments - 1 provided    TakeTwo d:\desktop\twittersearch\taketwo\taketwo\taketwo.cpp    23  
Error   C2780   '_FwdIt1 std::search(_FwdIt1,_FwdIt1,_FwdIt2,_FwdIt2,_Pr)': expects 5 arguments - 1 provided    TakeTwo d:\desktop\twittersearch\taketwo\taketwo\taketwo.cpp    23
```

The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string token;

int main()
{
    int menu_choice;
    cout << "Main Menu:\n";
    cout << "1. Search for \"winner\" \n";

    cout << "Please choose an option: ";
    cin >> menu_choice;

    if (menu_choice == '1') {
        token == "winner";
        search(token);
    } else {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a valid option\n";
        system("Pause");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }

    return 0;
}

void search(string &token)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("sampleTweets.csv");

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File opened successfully" << "\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error opening file" << "\n";
    }

    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        if (line.find(token) != string::npos) {
            int n = line.find(",");
            char c;
            line[n] = ' '; //Changes the comma spacing
            line.erase(remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), [](char chr) { return chr == '\"' || chr == '\'' || chr == ','; }), //Removes the characters " ' and , from the strings
                line.end());
            line.erase(n + 1, 1); //Removes the 'b' from the beginning of each tweet
            cout << line << endl;
        }

    }

    fin.close();
    char anykey;
    cout << "press any key";
    cin >> anykey;

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perils of `using namespace std;`. Since you never declare or define the `search` function before it's used, the compiler is assuming you mean `std::search` which is part of the `<algorithm>` header. Making sure to [declare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) your function before it's used will fix the error in this case.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string token;

// Forward declare search before first use
void search(string &token);

int main()
{
    int menu_choice;
    cout << "Main Menu:\n";
    cout << "1. Search for \"winner\" \n";

    cout << "Please choose an option: ";
    cin >> menu_choice;

    if (menu_choice == '1') {
        token == "winner";
        search(token);
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a valid option\n";
        system("Pause");
        system("cls");
        main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```